# Django URL Path from DB file value

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to create 'project' pages that have their paths generated with the
{{ project.title }} values, rather than the current method I have which uses ints. I don't quite understand how I can do this, but feel I am close?

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    technology = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.FilePathField(path='projects/static/img/')
    live = models.URLField()
    source = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.project_index, name="projects"),
    path("<int:pk>/", views.project_details, name="project_details"),  # PK for Primary Key
]
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Project

# Create your views here.
def project_index(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    context = {'projects': projects}
    return render(request, 'projects/project_index.html', context)

def project_details(request, pk):
    project = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {'project': project}
    return render(request, 'projects/project_details.html', context)
```

I figure `path("<int:pk>/",` will need to be a slug, but I just cannot figure out how to tie in the DB data.
Potentially `context = {'project': project}`?

Currently the url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/1/ - I am looking for http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/EXAMPLE/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `SlugField` to your `models.py` file:

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    technology = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.FilePathField(path='projects/static/img/')
    live = models.URLField()
    source = models.URLField()
    slug = models.SlugField(default="", blank=True, null=False, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Project

# Create your views here.
def project_index(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    context = {'projects': projects}
    return render(request, 'projects/project_index.html', context)

def project_details(request, slug):
    project = Project.objects.get(slug=slug)
    context = {'project': project}
    return render(request, 'projects/project_details.html', context)
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.project_index, name="projects"),
    path("<slug:slug>/", views.project_details, name="project_details"),
]
```

Make sure to run `makemigrations` and then `migrate`.

Comment: I like this solution, but when I attempt it I get the following error? https://imgur.com/a/kuyASZe

Comment: Make sure to run `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: It now returns: https://imgur.com/a/jjTnlJi and the console responds with Not Found: /projects/example/

Comment: try adding a "/" after the slug url: `path("<slug:slug>/", views.project_details, name="project_details"),
]`

Comment: That resolved the above issue, but raises a new one. I must note, in the DB it is called Example with a capital, but trying both in the URL returns the same error, if that matters. https://imgur.com/a/JluZLUS

Comment: That means that the database object "example" does not exist. Try creating one through the admin page. Make sure to register your models on the `admin.py` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238295/discussion-between-leonardo-araujo-and-swamptiger24).

Answer (score 0):

urls.py

```py
    path("<title>/", views.project_details, name="project_details"),
```

views.py

```py
def project_details(request, title: str):
    project = Project.objects.filter(title=title).first()
    if project is None:
        titles = list(Project.objects.all().values_list('title', flat=True))
        msg = f'Project(title=title) not found. Exist titles are: {titles}'
        raise Exception(msg)
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, when attempting this I get the following error? https://imgur.com/a/OlzJmba

Comment: The site can not open. Please add the error into your problem.

Comment: The link still works fine for me? It states `no Project matches the given query`